# Design pattern recommendation for chain-of-responsibility with task delegation

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I have one interface with let's say 2 methods and has 3 different implementations.

```
public interface IFace {
    public void method1(Param param1);
    public void method2(Param param2);
}

public class A implements IFace {
    public void method1(Param param1){}
    public void method2(Param param2){}
}

public class B implements IFace {
    public void method1(Param param1){}
    public void method2(Param param2){}
}

public class C implements IFace {
    public void method1(Param param1){}
    public void method2(Param param2){}
}
```

Now I have a requirement as per which only one of those two methods needs modifications and there are some pre-conditions as per which I decide to call specific implementation and the pattern is in a way that I might have to go through those implementations one by one. This appeared like a perfect fit for chain of responsibility and I created that like this:

```
public interface IChain {
    public void method1(Param param1);
    public void setNextChain(IChain iChain);
} 

public class AA implements IChain {
    private IChain chain;

    private IFace a;

    public void method1(Param param1){
        if (thisConditionIsSatisfied(param1)) {
            a.method1(param1);
        } else {
            chain.method1();
        }
    }

    public void setNextChain(IChain chain){
        this.chain = chain
    }

    public void setA(IFace a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public class BB implements IChain {
    private IChain chain;

    private IFace b;

    public void method1(Param param1){
        if (thisConditionIsSatisfied(param1)) {
            b.method1(param1);
        } else {
            chain.method1();
        }
    }

    public void setNextChain(IChain chain){
        this.chain = chain
    }

    public void setA(IFace b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public class CC implements IChain {
    private IChain chain;

    public void method1(Param param1){
        if (thisConditionIsSatisfied(param1)) {
            //process it here
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't process request.")
        }
    }

    public void setNextChain(IChain chain){
        this.chain = chain
    }

}
```

As you can see, CC doesn't delegate to class C which was implementing IFace and is a completely new implementation.

This is a very small part that I am displaying but the problem effectively is the same that I see a lot of duplication in terms of condition evaluation, exception handling, calling the correct implementation of the interface etc.

Though this is much better than trying to extend the existing interface but I was wondering if there is any recommendation to make it better in terms of future extensibility or OOPS pattern following.

Comment: Isn't this question better suited for softwareengineering? (I really am asking I personally don't care that it's here)

Comment: @Oleg Yes, it would be better fit for SoftwareEngineering StackExchange

Comment: @VinceEmigh when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Thanks. Migrated to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/355538/design-pattern-recommendation-for-chain-of-responsibility-with-task-delegation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Although it looks as if it can be made to fit better design with less duplication, it just doesn't seem to be there. Your solution is excellent though, in my  opinion that's probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is not a Software Engineering question but a design related question. My answer as follows.

This overall follows Chain of responsibility (COR) Design pattern (except violation by class CC). In COR all concrete handlers (AA, BB, CC) should be of type Abstract Handler (better to have it as a place for common/ default handler code), bound in a chain. In your implementation CC breaks this contract and does not pass opportunity to next handler. If in a dynamic chain of N handlers if CC is head, only requests of type CC will be handled. Instead of throwing exception CC can call super.handle() and delegate to successor (as in following code).

As your main point, repeat code comes from contract to delegate it to successor (if handler can not handle, delegate to successor if one exists) this code can be placed in Abstract handler as shown and called by super.handle(). Instance of successor also kept with abstract handler.

What each handler does in handle() method is independent of COR related code. Only each concrete handler should behave like honest handler by extending from abstract handler.

```
public class AbsChain implements IChain {
    private IChain successor; // as each handler has it
    @Override
    public void method1(Param param1) {
        if (getSuccessor() != null) {
            getSuccessor().method1(param1);
        } else {
            // Control comes here for totally unhandled request
        }
    }
}

public class AA extends AbsChain {
    private IFace a;

    public void method1(Param param1){
        // Handle if you can 
        if (thisConditionIsSatisfied(param1)) {
            a.method1(param1);
        } else {
            //else allow next one to try (default behavior)
            super.handleRequest(param1);
        }
    }
}

public class CC implements IChain {

    public void method1(Param param1){
        if (thisConditionIsSatisfied(param1)) {
            //process it here
        } else {
            //throwing Ex here breaks the chain
            super.handleRequest(param1); // keep passing it
        }
    }
}
```